# Character level buffer modification

Tags: vimscript, neovim, buffers, functions, vimscript-python

It is possible to modify buffer at the line granularity. E.g. `:py3 vim.current.buffer[0] = "abc"`. But it deletes the attached marks even if a single character is replaced. Is it possible to modify the buffer characterwise? Something like `:py3 vim.current.buffer[0][0] = "a"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vim.current.buffer` list is a list of strings:

```
:pyx import vim; print(type(vim.current.buffer[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

and strings are immutable in Python; something like `a_str[2] = 'b'` doesn't work either. This is just a property of the Python programming language (and many other languages, including VimScript).

The general way to do this is to get the line and then modify it:

```
:pyx line = vim.current.buffer[0]            # hello
:pyx vim.current.buffer[0] = 'w' + line[1:]  # wello
```

Or shorter:

```
:pyx vim.current.buffer[0] = 'w' + vim.current.buffer[0][1:]
```

Or in VimScript with `getline()` and `setline()`.

Using things like `substitute()` or `str.replace()` in Python is also useful. With `substitute()` you can use `\%c` to replace a specific column:

```
:call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), '\%2c.', 'a', ''))
```

`\%2c` matches the next character (`.` for any character in this case) at this column, turning `hello` in to `hallo`. You can also match multiple columns; see `:help \%c` for details. I'm not sure how to call this from Python though but it's probably possible

Comment: Perfect! `setline(lnum) = "content"` preserves the marks. `vim.current.buffer[lnum] = "content"` seems to use a different function internally.

Comment: Except for movement, `:execute 'normal! r'.replacement_char` would almost be easier, heh